# iPhone : run .app to iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, .app

I got a .app folder from a developer friend.

I would try his application and run .app to my iPhone Simulator, without XCode.

Is there a way to run this .app to my iPhone Simulator ? Of course this .app has been built for iPhone Simulator target.

Comment: Have you tried dragging the folder to the simulator app icon in the launch bar and dropping it?  I'm not on my mac so I can't try it, but that seems to work with most apple stuff.

Comment: Safari tries to download .app file, and fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication path_to_your_app/YourFavouriteApp.app/YourFavouriteApp
```

Comment: But, it doens'nt install application. Have you got a link for documentation about "Iphone Simulator" command tool ?