# iPhone simulator not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-lion

I'm new to Xcode development. I installed Xcode 4.3.1 on my Lion-based mac and unset the hidden flag on ~/Library.

I read about the iPhone / iPad simulator here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31015/how-do-i-run-the-ipad-simulator-to-test-a-website-on-my-mac - and also here [iPhone : run .app to iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362852/iphone-run-app-to-iphone-simulator) - but the instructions at this page suggest this path which **does not exist** on my machine. (I do not have the /Developer folder at all). I presume Xcode 4.3.1 should have installed this but it has not.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

This page here on stackoverflow suggested the library location for the simulator - 
[iPhone simulator path not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738019/iphone-simulator-path-not-found)

```
/Users/Tim/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications
```

All I have in this folder is a guid folder, and there are not any apps that I can locate inside this guid folder. Is there a place I have to go to download this? I wasn't able to find any information about it on the Apple developers page.

Comment: Check also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738019/iphone-simulator-path-not-found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Xcode 4.3 the simulator is no longer in a separate directory. It is within the Xcode application bundle. So for me it is a path that looks like:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

Comment: Great stuff, I wouldn't have thought to look inside the package itself silly me